# Is it possible set different AccessToken ExpireTime for different grant_type in Owin OAuth middleware?

Tags: .net, owin

It is my current understanding that it is only possible to set the access token expiry time globally using the property:

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan
```

and it applies to all grant_type values.

Is it possible to set a different expiry time based on different values for grant_type? For example, grant_type = password may have longer expiry time than authorization_code.

Comment: I wanted to ask the exact same question and am disappoint to find just tumble-weed here. Sorry I can't help.